# Handle UL Tags in Web Scraping, Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrpe "Table:" & "Release date: " from the URL: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/type/data?geoname=A0002&p=0#

I am using salenium web driver to scrape

Below is the tags present in source.

```
<ul>
    # Some HTML Data
</ul>

<ul data-offset="0">
    <li class="ndm-item">
    # Some HTML Tags
</ul>

<ul>
    # Some HTML Tags
</ul>
```

I want to get the details of SECOND tag "ul" where "data-offset" present

```
for Class_L1 in Soup.findAll('ul', {'data-offset': "0"}):
    for Class_L2 in Class_L1('li',  {'class': 'ndm-item'}):
    for Class_L3 in Class_L2('div',  {'class': 'ndm-result-container'}):
        for Class_L4 in Class_L3.findAll('div',  {'class': 'ndm-result-productid'}):
        Table = str(Class_L4.get_text()).strip()
        print(Table)
        for Class_L4 in Class_L3.findAll('div',  {'class': 'ndm-result-date'}):
        Release_Date = str(Class_L4.get_text()).strip()
        print(Release_Date)
```

Problem is source contains multiple 'ul' tags with data-offset="0", I just want to get details from SECOND 'ul' tag which contains data-offset="0"

Comment: Could not you just get `Class_L1[1]` if you just want the second `ul` at each time? I know it seems pretty dummy but maybe I did'nt understood the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an nth-of-type selector. This is based on:

> I want to scrape "Table:" & "Release date: " from the URL

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/type/data?geoname=A0002&p=0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
tableInfo = [table.text for table in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#all .ndm-result-productid")))]
dates = [date.text for date in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#all .ndm-result-date:nth-child(2)")))]
results = list(zip(tableInfo, dates))
print(results)
driver.quit()
```